# Canonical parabolics vs Levi subgroups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. The Jacobson-Morozov theorem gives a method of embedding any unipotent element into an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple, which in turn induces a parabolic subgroup of $G$ given by of $\mathfrak p=\oplus_{n\ge0}\mathfrak g_n$, called the canonical parabolic.

It is known, e.g. [from the discussion here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206624/characterizations-of-jacobson-morozov-parabolics-associated-to-a-nilpotent), that not all parabolic subgroups of $G$ arise as canonical parabolics as we range over unipotent elements of $G$. But I am wondering if all Levi subgroups of $G$ do arise from the Jacobson-Morozov triples, namely from the collection of all such $\mathfrak g_0$?

Comment: I think no -- in the link, for $G = SL_3$, only the Borel and $G$ appear as canonical parabolics, so the only Levis that appear are the torus and $G$.